# How to assign mappings in constructor?

Tags: solidity, remix

Sorry if this seems dumb, I'm just getting started w/ Solidity. These are concepts I've never dealt with. I'm trying to save space by using bytes arrays, but I'm quickly getting lost. Please help.

Source

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract TestConstructorAssigns {

    mapping(uint8 => bytes32[5]) questions;

    constructor() public payable {
        questions[1] = ["first part of question", "second", "third", "and so ", "on"];
    }
}
```

Compiler

```
browser/dass42-test.sol:51:24: TypeError: Type string memory[5] memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type bytes32[] storage ref.
        questions[1] = ["first part of question", "second", "third", "and so ", "on"];
                       ^------------------------------------------------------------^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the compiler is telling you, you're using `string`s where you need `bytes32`s. You can fix this with an explicit cast (only needs to be on the first element):

```
questions[1] = [bytes32("first part of question"), "second", "third", "and so ", "on"];
```

Comment: Oh heavens, what a relief. That was like "infinite gas" less painful than I was expecting :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
questions[1] = [bytes32("first part of question"), bytes32("second"), bytes32("third"), bytes32("and so "), bytes32("on")];
```

Comment: @smarx's answer is correct, bc the compiler can "deduce the common type" from the explicit conversion of the first element in the array.